# Choosing column values to minimize filesize of SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, compression

I have an SQLite database in which I altered a table to add a column that will contain a kind of permanently unique ID for each row (in addition to the existing `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` which might be reassigned and thus not permanent). I also want to avoid accidentally mixing up the normal ID's and the new "permanent ID's", therefor I decided to use a `TEXT` column and give each value a prefix, for example `pid-`.

So I simply added a column named `perma_id` with the type `TEXT` and ran `UPDATE mytable SET perma_id = 'pid-' || _rowid_` to assign values for the existing rows. I then saved and compacted/vacuumed the database and compressed it into a zip-file because I will include it in an Android APK.

I noticed that the filesize had gone up from 379kB to 417kB after adding the new column. This is of course expected. But as an experiment, I thought maybe I could reduce the filesize by just using `p...` instead of `pid-...` for the `perma_id` column values, so I reassigned all the values. But to my surprise, the filesize had instead *increased* to 420kB! I experimented a bit further, and I can consitently get the (compressed) filesize o become 417kB with `pid-...` and 420kB with `p...`. As expected, using an `INTEGER` column reduces the filesize further, but only to 414kB.

This makes me wonder - what is the black magic behind the smaller file size when using a longer string as a prefix in the `perma_id` column? And is there a way to determine which string would produce the smallest filesize?

### Edit

Just tried using the prefix `perma-id-...`, which results in a compressed file size of 414kB - i.e. same as using an `INTEGER` column with just the number after the prefix. So I tried `very-long-permanent-id-with-the-value-...` as prefix - 413kB. Mind = blown.

Comment: The long repeated string is probably a lot easier to compress than the shorter ones.

Comment: @Shawn Yeah, but the numbers after the string vary for each row, and they are the same in all test cases. What I find really odd is that using INTEGER and the numbers alone (1-2914) produces a larger file than using a 38 character prefix before each number. Sure, the repeated prefix might be very compressable, but the numbers still vary the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running the [VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) command on the database before zipping each time?

When you shortened the Primary Key values it may have reduced the size of the data but kept the .DB file the same size, as SQLite doesnt automatically reduce the file size it just marks chunks of the file as 'overwriteable'. Until, that is, you run the VACUUM to throw away all this spare space.

I'm guessing the 'overwriteable' proportion of your file was hard to zip. Then when it got filled up with lots of repeating text saying "permanent-id-with-the-value-" - it got easier to zip!

Comment: It's been 5 years, but I'm 99.99% confident I did "vaccum" it, since I mention it in the question.

Comment: Sorry @Magnus i didn't spot that! My mind is equally as blown then in that case! I can only assume then that it only vaccuums down to the nearest whole page, perhaps for anyone else encountering this then reducing the [page size](https://www.sqlite.org/pgszchng2016.html) is the way forward. Though this could affect performance if you're writing to your DB a lot in the app itself.